# How to Access rowId of selectedrow of JQGrid in JSP

Tags: jqgrid, jsp-tags, struts2-jquery

I have a page designed with JQGrid in a div and the form (with fields) in another div.
When I select a row in JQGrid I want to populate data for fields in the form based on row id.

```
<div id="data_div" class="results">
<table id="grid_table">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="pager" />
</div>
<div id="people-info">
<table><tr><td> <s:textfield key="act.actpeople[0].firstName" /></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

This works with hardcoding 0,1,2 indexing.  I want to write something like:

```
<div id="people-info">
<table><tr><td> <s:textfield key="act.actpeople[${i}].firstName" /></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Using Struts 2 and JSON for JQGrid;  In my javascript am obtaining selected row Id but how can I get that Id for indexing?  What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your asking how to dynamically populate data inanother form based on what row is selected in your jqGrid. Inside your jqGrid setup you can use the

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
   var idRowData = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);

   //set your form fields to the selected row column values
   FormField1.val(idRowData.Column1Name);
   FormField2.val(idRowData.Column2Name);
   //etc.....
}
```

Comment: columns in form are additional details of person; if i can get index i can get data. i am trying hidden field and setting its value to rowId; but how to access the value from hidden field?

Comment: The same method, `idRowData.Column1NameOfHiddenField`

Comment: though it didn't help; I accepted it because it helped partially. :) Thanks Mark

Comment: What was the solution to your problem?